# Is it compatible with the 2.7x update, or should I use Select python Interpreter 3 or 2.7x to use Python for Maya?

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, maya, interpreter

I looked up that 3 is not supported in Maya and uses 2.7.
[Autodesk Klnowledge](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Maya-Scripting/files/GUID-C0F27A50-3DD%206-454C-A4D1-9E3C44B3C990-htm.html)

This site just says 2.7, but there are many versions of 2.7 and I don't know which one to choose.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNFgRUD2w68
(This is 3.7.1)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNFgRUD2w68
(This is 3.6.4)

- Am I correct in recognizing that Python 2.6.8 does not support Python 2.7?
- does Python 2.7.18 support the past 2.7 or 2.7.3?
- Is Python 3.8.3 also including and supporting Python 2.7.18?
- Which is the best version for Maya 2018.6/2019?

***environment***

- Windows 10 Pro 64bit
- vscode version1.47.3
- Maya2018.6/2019

Comment: Welcome @newguy, I'd recommend trying to use the minimum necessary description if possible.

Comment: @newguy As mateuszb said, 2.7.18 is a version of the 2.7 series, the two are compatible, and the difference between them is very limited. You could try to use the 2.7.18 version, If there is an issue during use, please show the details.

Answer (score 1):

2.7.18 is compatible with 2.7 python requirement. The .18 refers to `post-release` corrections which should not cause incompatibilities. Specifically, `post-releases ... address minor errors in a final release that do not affect the distributed software (for example, correcting an error in the release notes)` (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/)

Python 3.8 is incompatible with 2.7: significant changes have been introduced on the way.